# Python var operand in c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

What is mean Python `.var` operand using with OpenCV Mat and how convert it to c++?

Code: `cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()`

Comment: Computes the variance along the flattened array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python version of OpenCV uses numpy arrays instead of the cv::Mat class in c++ (those two are somehow inter-operable, so that each time the python api call c++ code the storage of the numpy array is transferred to a cv::Mat).

the var operand is thus the one from numpy: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html

For interactions between python and c++ I would recommand you to use PyBind11: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html

If the question is how to call a similar operator in c++, well, you can use the meanstddev function from openCV: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=meanstd#meanstddev

Pay attention that the variance is the square of the standard deviation, so you have to square the result if you really want the variance and not the standard deviation.